# If a function is not-strictly-increasing, is there an interval on which it is weakly decreasing?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Suppose a continuous function $f$ is not strictly-increasing, i.e, there are $a,b$ such that $a<b$ and $f(a) \geq f(b)$. Does there exists an interval $a',b'$, with $a\leq a' < b' \leq b$, in which $f$ is weakly-decreasing, i.e:
$$
\forall x,y \in[a',b']: 
~
x<y \implies f(x)\geq f(y)
$$
?

Initially I thought it was trivial, but now I do not see how to prove it...

EDIT: if this is not true, what minimal assumption should be made on $f$ to make it true? (e.g, is it sufficient to assume that $f$ is differentiable? smooth?)

Comment: I suspect Weierstrass's nowhere differentiable function might be a counterexample.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will copy your notation in my answer.

Suppose that $f$ is continuously differentiable on $[a,b]$. I claim that in this case there is an interval $(a',b')$ such that $f$ is weakly-decreasing on this interval.

Note that if $f'(c) < 0$, then there is an open neighborhood of $c$ such that $f'(x) < 0$ on this open neighborhood and hence $f$ is strictly decreasing on this open neighborhood.

Hence, we are done if there is any $c \in [a,b]$ such that $f'(c) < 0$. So suppose that $f'(x) \geqslant 0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$.

Now note, that if $f'(x) \geqslant 0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$, then we have $f(a) \leqslant f(b)$. With equality if and only if $f'(x) = 0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$. By assumption $f(a) \geqslant f(b)$. Hence $f(a) = f(b)$ and $f'(x) = 0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$ and hence $f(x) = f(a) = f(b)$ for all $x \in [a,b]$ and we are done.

---

Note that this proof generalizes to piecewise continuously differentiable $f$. Partition the interval $[a,b]$ into pieces $[a_{i},b_{i}]$ such that $f$ is continuously differentiable on each $[a_{i},b_{i}]$. If $f$ is strictly increasing on all pieces then $f$ is strictly increasing, a contradiction to the assumption that this is not so. Hence $f$ is not-strictly-increasing on at least one of the pieces $[a_{i},b_{i}]$ and the previous proof applies.

---

Some words about the minimality of this assumption. According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function#Some_basic_applications_and_results), any function that is monotonic on an interval is differentiable almost everywhere. This shows that any function that is differentiable *nowhere* is a counter-example to your claim.

This means that the functions that we are not decided about yet are the functions that are almost everywhere continuously differentiable, but not piecewise differentiable. I must admit that I have trouble imagining what such a function would like.

Comment: So assuming any monotonic is diff a.e gives an example where claim works, how does that show that if we have a nowhere diff function gives a counterexample? [I may just be being dense with this question...]

Comment: I could have been a bit clearer. Suppose that $f$ is nowhere differentiable. Suppose furthermore that there is an interval where $f$ is weakly-decreasing, then in particular $f$ is monotonic on this interval. Hence $f$ is differentiable almost everywhere in this interval, but this contradicts the assumption that $f$ is nowhere differentiable.

Comment: Got it, thanks! (already upvoted).